# My program is asking too many times for input. C while loop

Tags: c, input, while-loop

My program is asking too many times for input, after the first input. Source code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
typedef struct data{
    char name[100];
    int n_in_class;
    int grade;
    struct data *p;
}data;

void add(data *begin);

int main(void){
    char n;
    data *begin = malloc(sizeof(data));

    while(1 == 1){
        printf("Do you want to add new student(n) or (y)");
            n = getchar();
        if(n == 'n'){
            break;
        }
        else if(n == 'y'){
            add(begin);
        }
    }
    data *temp = begin;
    while(temp != NULL){
        printf("%s", temp->name);
        temp = temp->p;
    }
}

void add(data *begin){
    data *new = malloc(sizeof(data));
    printf("enter name: ");
        scanf("%s", &new->name);
    printf("Enter number in class: ");
        scanf("%i", &new->n_in_class);
    printf("enter grade: ");
        scanf("%i", &new->grade);
    data *temp = begin;
    while(1==1){
        if(temp->p == NULL){
            temp->p = new;
            break;
        }
        else{
            temp = temp->p;
        }
    }
}
```

The program starts, I enter y and it's calling the add function, I enter all information without problems, after I finish with entering information and when it comes time to ask for input again its printing the message "Do you want to add new student(n) or (y)" twice. I have try with different functions for getting input scanf, fgets, getline and getchar.

Comment: Improve your coding habbit use `while(1)` instead of `while(1 == 1)`

Comment: I don't see anything bad in 1==1, I don't see any reason to call this "bad habit";

Comment: you should always write code which clear, simple and short. You only want to run a infinite loop then why `1==1` when only `1` can do the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you input <kbd>y</kbd> or <kbd>n</kbd> and press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, the new line character is also in the input buffer, you need to remove this newline character before the next loop.

```
if(n == 'n'){
    break;
}
else if(n == 'y'){
    add(begin);
}
getchar();   //consumes new line
```

Answer (score 0):

To consume the newline in the input buffer,
you can also use
`scanf(" %c", &n) ;` - a space before the format descriptor(%c)

in place of the first `getchar()`

or 
you can also use

`getc(stdin)'` in place of the second `getchar()` to achieve the same.